# Represent this situation in a class diagram

Tags: class, uml, diagram

I came across with these situation while building a class diagram for a system, I never cross with a similar situation so I am not sure how to do it

I have this two classes "Swimmer" and "Swimming Match", the issue is with scheduling the match. The match as 3-4 days where where it can occur and the Swimmers can pick the days where they would prefer it to happen, how do I represent this exactly ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have a class for `Swimmer`, another class for `Swimming Match` and then you have a couple of options:

1. Use an association class to represent each acceptable day when the match can occur
2. Create a new class `AcceptableDay` which has three properties: `Day` (the day it could occur), `swimmer` (an instance of the `Swimmer` class) and `match` (an instance of `Swimming Match`)

For an example of an association class, see [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/content/RationalEdge/sep04/bell/#N10370).

Comment: Thanks I was planning to do something like option 2 but I wasn't really too sure, so I wanted a second opinion.  What would you do if you also wished to also have a chosen date attribute? Is it possible for both the acceptable day and chosen date co-exist

Comment: As with any design question there is no single correct answer, but follow rules like don't repeat yourself, keep it simple, reduce coupling etc will help.